# The transcript link for podcast 387 goes to an error page saying that the site is not configured (from France?)

Tags: bug, podcast

The "TRANSCRIPT" link on the podcast-387 page:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/10/26/podcast-387-the-first-ten-years-of-our-programming-lives/?cb=1&_ga=2.220719320.156857669.1635256381-1409720708.1583260978
(the one under "Show notes", just above the tags: line)

[image]

leads to: **https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/the-first-ten-years-of-our-programming-lives/transcript/**

and (for me, but not for someone I talked with in chat) that page says:

> **Unconfigured Simplecast Domain** You are seeing this page because your website is not configured properly. [Learn more](https://help.simplecast.com/custom-domains-for-your-simplecast-site)

[image]

I am located in France, so may it be a local thing?

Someone asked me if I could see transcript for #386: I can see that one.
I then edited that URL and kept only the beginning (https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/) and saw the list.

I then clicked on the link for episode 387's transcript: I do see it! (https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/the-first-ten-years-of-our-programming-lives)

**The issue: the #387 page "TRANSCRIPT" link (under Show notes, above the tags) has a link with a trailing "/" in it: https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/the-first-ten-years-of-our-programming-lives/transcript/, but it should be: https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/the-first-ten-years-of-our-programming-lives/transcript**

Comment: I'm in Northern Europe, and I see the actual transcript just fine.

Comment: Do other transcripts have the same problem? e.g. [for #386](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/quality-code-is-the-easiest-to-delete).

Comment: @WaiHaLee : that one works fine for me ( https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/quality-code-is-the-easiest-to-delete ), but the one I posted still does not work. Interresting...

Comment: weird: I edited your link, ie kept it untile "/episodes/", and see a list of transcripts. When I click on the latest one, for episode 387, I DO see the page! ( https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/the-first-ten-years-of-our-programming-lives )

Comment: The URL in your last comment doesn't end in `/transrcript` whereas the linked URL (in the podcast page and your question) does.

Comment: It works for me in Paris. Only a vue-gtag error in console.

Comment: @WaiHaLee : I edited the Q with the issue (their link has an additionnal "/" after "/transcript", breaking the url). Thank you for the link to #386, which allowed me to poke further and find the correct link

Comment: @WaiHaLee : do you see the same link I see on the #387 blog post? (at the same location, ie under "Show notes" and above "tags:")

Comment: Yes - for me the transcript link ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ4D8.png)) points to a URL ending in `/transcript/`. But for me it's fine whether I have the trailing `/` on the end or not. (I'm in the UK).

Comment: @WaiHaLee : that is very strange indeed... if I take off the "/" it works, if I add it back i get the error page. This could be also a different configuration (for france or europe) ?... and thus I can't close/answer this question yet and will wait until it attracts the attention of the so team.