# "Transcript" link for Podcast 390 is broken

Tags: bug, podcast

Not sure if this is the correct place to report this, but I tried to look at the [transcript](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/web3-dao-crypto-blockchain-nft-society/transcript/) for the latest SO podcast [Podcast 390: Web3 won’t save us](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/11/05/podcast-390-web3-wont-save-us/) and I got an error saying the website is not configured properly:

[image: Unconfigured Simplecast Domain]

Looks like [Podcast 387: The first ten years of our programming lives](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/10/26/podcast-387-the-first-ten-years-of-our-programming-lives/) has the same problem.  There may be others.

Followup:
Looks like the problem is a trailing slash in the transcript URL.  If I edit the URL in my browser address bar to remove the trailing slash, I can get to the transcript.

Comment: Both links were OK for me just now.

Comment: This earlier report seems related: [The transcript link for podcast 387 goes to an error page saying that the site is not configured (from France?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412562/11407695)